# Can I use the Raspberry Pi as a Soundcard

Tags: usb, audio, usb-audio

I have an [HifiBerry AMP2](https://www.hifiberry.com/products/ampplus/), which is a RPi hat that lets the RPi act as an audio amplifier. Now I want to connect my PC (Mac) to the RPi, but it does not have a line- or mic-in. So I am wondering if I can make the RPi act as an external USB-soundcard, i.e. connect the RPi via USB to my PC and have the PC recognize it as an external soundcard.

Is that possible?

Comment: Which Pi do you have?

Comment: All of them except Zero

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a solid answer for you, but since I know the pi zero has [USB-OTG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go), I figured it might be able to do what you want. So I did some research on using the pi zero to emulate usb devices and found things like this [tutorial on setting it up as a usb mass storage device](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/pi-zero-w-smart-usb-flash-drive/) that didn't seem very easy. Then I simply did a web search for "pi zero act as usb sound card" and found a [similar question to yours](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1237970). It didn't definitively explain how to do it the way you asked, but discussed a way of doing it over the network which seems like it might work for you instead. Or you may have more luck with similar searches and more research than I did.

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer, I am looking into this